# Adding a constant after finding harmonic conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

The question asked me to find the harmonic conjugate of $u$ and then express $f(x,y)$ in terms of $z$. I found the conjugate. I also reasoned that it must be the expanded form of $z^2$. However, they give the answer and it includes a $c$. Why is this?

**My answer:** $$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2+2xyi$$
$$f(z)=z^2$$

**Given answer:**
$$f(z)=z^2+c$$

Comment: Its a constant ..

Comment: @ArchisWelankar right, but why do they include it there? It makes sense when including it after finding the harmonic conjugate but I didn't think that'd be so for the $f(z)$ as well.

Comment: Seems similar like integration constant